# In the sentence "Wait to be seated" is it in passive voice or is seated and adjective?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, passive-voice, active-vs-passive, imperative-sentences

I can figure out this sentence is an imperative sentence but is the word "seated" a verb or an adjective? and is it active or passive voice?

Comment: "To be seated" is a passive verb phrase, as evident by the possibility of a _by_ phrase, as in "Wait to be seated by the host".

Comment: @BillJ and how would it be in active form?

Comment: "Wait for the host to seat you".